# download API mongodb, react, nodejs and etc

Tags: api

I have very bad internet, so I want to download the api(mongodb, react, nodejs) I need to work on a project on a local computer, tell me if this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably play with `"npm cache add some-package.tar.bz2"` or with [npm-proxy](https://blog.theodo.com/2016/01/speed-up-npm-install-with-a-nexus-proxy-to-cache-packages/) but it will probably require too much effort (or will not resolve all issues).

**Alternative way would be to setup proxy server**(for example squid) to keep once downloaded files localy at your server/computer.
This way you configure your system (and tools) to use yours proxy server.

So when vagrant, apt, npm, grunt or some other tool need some file from internet during the build it will download it only once and get it out of the cache of proxy server during subsequent requests.

majority of tools favour environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.
So you could setup docker container, virtual machine or just service (squid has windows binaries as well) and configure your system to use proxy server, i.e. add environment variables either globaly or in bash file for build process only.

Lets suppose you configured your squid at docker container with IP address 172.17.0.34. then your build script would look like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export HTTP_PROXY=172.17.0.34:3128
export HTTPS_PROXY=172.17.0.34:3128

npm install
```

For it to take global effect you could place these two lines into your **/etc/environment** file:

```
HTTP_PROXY=172.17.0.34:3128
HTTPS_PROXY=172.17.0.34:3128
```